# Font Sizing issue with viewports larger than 1600px

Tags: html, css

I need some explanation on vh.

`html{font-size:16px;}   //Default  Shows Perfectly on my 1920px width monitor`

`html{font-size:1em;} // 16px   Shows Perfectly on my 1920px width monitor`

`html{font-size:1vh;} // 19.2px Shows VERY tiny on my 1920px width monitor`

Why would a font size that is LARGER than the default display as a much smaller font on my monitor?

Comment: `1vh` is 1% of view height, not view width (that would be `1vw`), so it likely won't be 19.2px unless you have a square monitor.

Comment: OMG!  I cannot believe I did that. Not enough coffee!  Thanks!